# Apache Camel и Json

Tags: java

Хочу десериализовать Json объект в Java object внутри роутера Camel.

Вот собственно объект выглядит как-то так.

```
  [
  "test",
  {
    "name": "1",
    "key": "4b588b18"
  }
]
```

Хочу десериализовать его в такой объект

```
public class SQSLargePay {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Собственно перепробовал кучу методов. Из последнего - вот такая вот нелепая попытка.

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(exchange.getIn().getBody());
                            SQSLargePay sqs = new Gson().fromJson(json, SQSLargePay.class);
                            System.out.println(sqs.getName());
```

И получаю что-то типа такого

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Ещё проблема в том, что `exchange.getIn().getBody()` - это ArrayList, поэтому я вообще без понятия, как связать все это. Мне нужно просто получить key/value, чтобы выполнить следующее действие.

Вообще вопрос сводится к следующему. Как подцепить в Apache Camel кастомный Десериалайзер для Json?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю написать свой процессор. Для этого нужно создать класс, реализующий интерфейс [Processor](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Processor.html).
В нем необходимо реализовать всего один метод public void process(Exchange exchange)